# Added Javascripts to WordPress do not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I added these lines at the end of `functions.wp-scripts.php`:

```
function web_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'web_script', 'main.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('web_script');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'web_script' );
```

In the `main.js`, I just have `alert(hi)`, but I don't see anything when I browse to pages. Any Idea?

Is there any better way to add scripts?

Comment: Look in browser dev tools network to see if file is even loaded. My bet is your path is wrong. And no to *"better way"*...this is the appropriate and documented way to include scripts

Comment: @charlietfl   If I put the script in the /wp-includes/js, how should I define its path?

Comment: not a good place to put it due to wp upgrades. Should never put anything in `wp-includes`. Really doesn't seem like you have done much research on this

Comment: @charlietfl, Unfortunately, the resources I have found misguided me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you `require()` your `functions.wp-scripts.php` inside your `functions.php`? As far as I know it will not get loaded by default.

Furthermore, you have to pass a valid filepath to `wp_register_script` as second parameter.

If you script is, for example under `wp-content/themes/your-theme/main.js`, use:

```
wp_register_script( 'web_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/main.js';
```

Further information:
  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/